# Delayed ACK in TCP

Tags: tcp

So I've got this strange problem with a TCP-stack. We're migrating a system from a Cortex-A5 to Cortex-A55 with all the joy that follows and we've used the TCP stack before, just another version and with other drivers. So after bumping the version of FreeRTOS+TCP to the latest tag everything works perfectly, in one direction. E.g., we have an FTP server running on the system and uploading stuff works great but not downloading. If I do a packet capture in Wireshark I, to my surprise, see that its Filezilla on Windows that is not acking the stream. So being a resource constrained system we can't waste an infinite amount of memory on frame-buffers in the ethernet stack and thus run out of buffers fairly quick.

But why is this happening? It sort of looks like a delayed ACK from the windows side only that it NEVER ACKs, I even changed the timeout here to 5000ms just to make sure we were not seeing the effects of sloppy time-keeping on the client side, still no ACK... We also tried using a Linux client with pretty much the same results only Linux was even harsher, hanging up on us with RST. We have plenty of other ethernet-based communication (like UDP and ICMP) working great and it looks like Windows and Linux are to blame for the problems although I'm sure they're not.

If I understand correctly, which I probably don't, a TCP stream can be ACKed at any position and moment. Every frame does not need ACKing, it can be done in a cumulative fashion which is even recommended (1 ACK for every other data frame, right?) but an ACK must never take more than 500ms to arrive back at the sender.

So... to me it looks like both Windows and Linux are blatantly ignoring that 500ms time limit. I realize that there must be a valid reasoning behind this but I just can't find this info anywhere! After that time expires I start seeing retransmissions in Wireshark which I suppose makes sense. Another interesting note is that choking the throughput in the driver layer to 1 frame / ms makes the ACKs from Windows start appearing so it must be related to throughput in some way.

I was not expecting "special treatment" from other IP-stacks based on, seemingly, how many frames I send.

Comment: *"So... to me it looks like both Windows and Linux are blatantly ignoring that 500ms time limit."* - if this would be the case then other communication would have a problem too, not only with your device. So there is likely something else going on. Unfortunately you provide only the interpretation of what you see, not the actual raw data before your interpretation. It is not even clear where you do the packet capture, i.e. if its on the client or on the server or somewhere in between.

Comment: *"It is not even clear where you do the packet capture"* - If you are missing ACK then make sure that the packets to ACK actually arrive on the system where the ACK should be generated, i.e. capture the incoming and outgoing packets on the system where the missing ACK should have been generated. A common problem is to have wrong assumptions about the MTU of the link on the sender side which results in too large packets which then gets lost. This is especially true when lots of data are transferred, i.e. FTP data connection vs. FTP control connection.